# moving some of the data from a table to another in excel

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, range

The sheet "A" got some data I need to copy/replicate in sheet "B". No links, just the values while maintaining the format. The data I want to move have the value "1" in column "V".

Row 1 will be a header which I need to replicate. The V column will show "1" until "0", but wont go back to one (if it makes sense ... it wont be {1, 1, 1, 0, ..., 1} but always like {1, 1, 1, 0, ..., 0}

```
Sub shL_to_shD()

Dim intNumberOfLinesToMove    As Integer
Dim i1                        As Integer
Dim i2                        As Integer

intNumberOfLinesToMove = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("shL").Range("V2:V31"), "1")

i1 = 0
i2 = 0

For i2 = 0 To 20
   For i1 = 0 To intNumberOfLinesToMove
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("shD").Range("A1").Offset(i1, i2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("shL").Range("A1").Offset(i1, i2).Value
   Next
Next

End Sub
```

This will replicate the data, but my format is not the one from the "shL" sheet, which makes date and time columns quite horrible to look at. How do I keep the formatting, and not just getting the values? :-)

Comment: You can use `Copy` instead of setting the values directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Copy` and then `PasteSpecial`, eg:

Instead of:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("shD").Range("A1").Offset(i1, i2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("shL").Range("A1").Offset(i1, i2).Value
```

Use:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ShL").Range("A1").Offset(i1,i2).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ShD").Range("A1").Offset(i1,i2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```